# Where are exceptions inside tasks stored?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, exception

If I'll uncomment the line with `Wait()` or `startNew.Result` in the following sample I'll catch the `AggregateException`. Why can't I see any exceptions if these lines of code are commented?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Task<int> startNew = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => int.Parse(""), 
                                             TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            //int result = startNew.Result;
            //startNew.Wait();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);             
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catched in aggregated");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catched in general");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The end");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Skeet is right but his answer is not full.

I should add that if you will not invoke Wait() or Result than you can face the situation when Finalize method will be invoked on Task object and that call will check the presence of exceptions inside the inner task object collection of exceptions and then throw the UnobservedTaskException what leads to immediate application crash (so long as you don't register a callback for TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException what is strongly not recommended).

Answer (score 2):

> But why can't I see any exceptions if these lines of code are commented?

Because nothing's throwing them! You really don't *want* an exception from one thread to be thrown in a different thread at an arbitrary point without you doing anything to cause it.

The `Task<>` *remembers* the exceptions, but it's not going to throw them unless you specifically perform an operation such as `Wait()` or `Result`, as you've seen.

You can also check the errors using [`Task.Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx).

Comment: So am I right that ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() throws exception immediately because there is no mechanism to get the result or wait for completion?